# Need bridge header between .m and .c file

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have source sample consists of .m and .c file .

I want to use this sample in my objective c  project .

My question is there is need to use bridge header in this case ?

Also this project created on 2011 , and 
Its contain [self release] 
Which will generate errors because its old and deprecated, how I can resolve these old functions that generate errors like "release" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language is a subset of Objective-C so .c files are directly compatible with an Objective-C project.

Apparently your project used manual memory management.  Xcode has the ability to convert to ARC under the Edit->Convert menu.